# Mnemonics / keyboard accelerators for Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Can the Google Docs menus be accessed by their first letters - ie. mnemonics / accelerator keys? I am on *macOS*

Comment: Besides lacking research, this question isn't really about Apple products or their use as defined in the Help Center. Also, there is a help menu within Google Docs. Searching for "Key" gets you to the page with all the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: "lacking research"  Does that page mention the shortcut that I discovered. I hs already looked at it, tell me if I missed it but otherwise please recognize that it does not.

Comment: About the "off topic" Apparently the rules have changed over time?  In the past it was acceptable to describe macos-specific issues about cross platform tools. It _was_ acceptable.  Apparently the interpretation has changed towards a more strict  approach. Is there now _any_ appropriate place in SE family of sites for this [genre] of question?

Comment: The question was primarily put on hold for lack of research. What have you tried? Did you look up help texts etc but couldn’t find anything? Did you find key combos but couldn‘t make them work on whatever browser you are using? Without details nobody here can know where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: ok i assume folks will understand that basic searching had been performed.  i created this q&a because the combination is not documented afaict and i think the answer  can be useful to others.  note that i i only included the question after i had an answer ready that is neither obvious or readily found

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=key+combinations+google+docs&t=iphone&ia=web, the relevant support article is the first hit.

Comment: I did see that article . Previously  I did not notice the tabs in the middle: specifically switching to the "Computer" tab does show the shortcut.  That is a challenge of mine : navigating GUI's .  I overlook components when not expecting them

Comment: Interesting question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for this (*google* naturally..) and did not find it. But I came across the answer by trial and error: Use <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> - [first letter].